# How to query ceilometer config?

Tags: api, config, openstack, ceilometer

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to query openstack for the ceilometer configuration. In particular, I would like to be able to query an API for the sampling interval for different meters. Is this currently possible (I'm still trying to find my way around openstack)?

Answer (score 0):

I got some help on IRC, so I wanted to post the answer. In short, no. At least not at this time. There is a blueprint for the feature, but it is low priority and has not been implemented,

https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ceilometer/+spec/record-sample-periodicity